# How to simulate TCP (Flow Control and Congestion Control) in java?

Tags: java, tcpclient, tcpserver, flow-control, congestion-control

I'm trying to simulate flow control and congestion control in java. I have a simple code with a TCP-Client and TCP-Server, but I need to separate it into two parts:  Flow Control and Congestion control. Then, I need to capture TCP packets in WireShark to see what is the congestion window behaviour.

I have been reading about it, but I haven't found anything about this topic. Would someone give me an idea to start with this?

I have read Networking from Kurosse, but it just give an illustrative example on how TCP works.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this](https://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~marsic/books/CN/projects/tcp/) project from a [professor](https://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~marsic/) at Rutgers, The State University of New Jersey. Along with the source code, it also contains a [design document](https://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~marsic/books/CN/projects/tcp/tcp-sim_doc.pdf) on how to design a TCP Protocol Simulator that also details congestion control.

The relevant snippet from the design document that might help you would be

> Our default “network” consists of a single router (Figure 4). This model is based on certain assumptions about TCP operation. Our focus is on studying TCP congestion control and not other aspects of data networks. For this purpose, it suffices to abstract the whole network as a single “bottleneck” router.

Reference - Page 10, Section 1.3 - https://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~marsic/books/CN/projects/tcp/tcp-sim_doc.pdf